# Auto hide address bar not working

Tags: javascript, redirect, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I packaged an Sencha Touch 2 app with the following config.

```
viewport: {
  autoMaximize: true
},
```

It works properly and the address bar is not visible. Now I am trying to redirect from another web page (desktop web page) to mobile web page. This auto hide functionality doesn't work.

I redirect from web page to mobile page like :

```
<script>window.location = 'mobile/index.html' </script>
```

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have any error in the console ? Can we see it running somewhere ?

Comment: No there is no any error in console. When I change orientation address bar hides. So it may be issue something on viewport rendering. And if I go to direct mobile site URL then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Set the min-height of your viewport to a value higher than the height of your device and check if this helps. If so, set your viewport min-height to window.innerHeight using javascript to set it correctly for different mobile platforms.